# Saving dynamic search parameters before navigation in React

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I have a dynamic search component which filters pre-loaded search results based on a hook search string.

Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/4qp6xn1rkw

Currently, when you select one of the search results, it takes you to the result page, and when you press the "back" button, it takes you back, but the hook is reset, so all of the search parameters are lost.

I want to save the search parameters right before the user navigates away, so that when they go back, they can click on another search result in the same query.

I've considered saving them in local storage, but that introduces unwanted behavior when a user leaves the website and comes back later.

I was thinking about putting the search query into the URL right before I navigate away to the result page, but I can't find a reasonable way of doing this. (I'm using React Router V4)

It would also be great to have the URL update as the user searches, so that they can bookmark the search query for later use, but that's not the primary priority.

PS: If you wanna see my actual implementation, you can see it here: http://aesthetics.red

Comment: When clicking on the country from the link you provided, it does not navigate. are you open to use hooks ?

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI I added a link to my actual implementation of the search if you wanna see what I'm talking about. I'm currently using hooks for searching, but i wanna populate the initial hook values based on the URL params.

Comment: @VolodymyrBobyr How are you saving the filters(sports, STEM, etc) state? They seem to stay when we navigate back. I mean you can do the same for maintaining the search keyword.

Comment: @Ramesh interesting, I did not notice that. It's saved as a static variable. I bet that would work!

Comment: Yeah, you can just update the search keyword on every keypress and also make sure the static variable gets updated as well.

Comment: @Ramesh I found another solution by changing the url on keypress and using the url params to initialize the hooks. I'm using ```history.replace(`/?:search=${inputString}`)```